# Do silly-rings exist?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

A *ring* can be defined as a [near-ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring) satisfying two-sided distributivity, whose underlying additive group is Abelian. Negating this second stipulation, we obtain the following definition. A *silly-ring* is a near-ring satisfying two-sided distributivity, whose underlying additive group is **non**-Abelian.

Do silly-rings exist?

Comment: Fantastic title.

Comment: I take it you know distributivity implies additive abelianness in the usual ring axioms setting.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff, I did not know that. Proof?

Comment: @Pedro Only if there's a unit (which I consider to be the "usual ring axioms" too, I guess).

Comment: @RyanReich Aha.

Comment: @user18921 Distribute $(x + 1)(y + 1)$ both ways.

Comment: @RyanReich, nice.

Comment: Alternative to Ryan: $(1+1)(a+b)$ in both ways.

Comment: For fun: If your ring-thing satsifies $x^2=x$ for all $x$ but perhaps lacks an identity, it still has commutative addition. Or, more generally, the squares in a given ring-thing without unity commute under addition.

Comment: Less cleverly, if you just distribute $(a+b)(c+d)$ both ways, you get $ad+bc=bc+ad$. Well, $RR=R$ is weaker that "$R$ has a $1$", isn't it? (I wouldn't know, not an algebraist.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they exist. Let $(R,+)$ be any non-Abelian group. Define $xy=0$ for all $x,y\in R$. (Ask a silly question, . . .)

Answer (score 0):

The comments show that if near-rings are assumed to have unity, then silly-rings do not exist. Here's a slightly more general proposition, following along the lines of bof's comment.

**Proposition.** Consider a structure $(R,+,\cdot)$ such that

1. Two sided distributivity holds.
2. $+$ is associative
3. Both cancellation laws hold.

Then for all $x,y \in R$, we have that if $x$ factors as $ab$ and $y$ factors as $cd$, then $x+y=y+x$.

*Proof.* Distribute $(a+c)(b+d)$ both ways, and cancel.

Comment: Of course the two-sided cancellation law is equivalent to the conjunction of the two one-sided cancellation law.

Comment: @bof, it certainly folkows from the conjunction of the one-sided cancellation laws. Are you saying the converse holds?

Comment: $a+x=a+y\Rightarrow a+x+b=a+y+b\Rightarrow x=y$.

Comment: @bof, yep good point.

Comment: On the other hand, if you take the usual axioms for a ring (without identity) and replace the two one-sided distributive laws by the "two-sided distributive law" $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+ad+bc+bd$, you get something strictly weaker.

Comment: @bof, how do we know we cannot prove at least one of the identities, $x0=0$ and/or $0y=0$?

Comment: $0^2=0$ would suffice. However, there are easy examples of non-rings which obey the two-sided distributive law (as well as being an Abelian group under addition and a semigroup under multiplication). In those things, of course, $0^2\ne0$. By the way, in the first printing of Kelley's *General Topology*, the definition of a ring in Chapter 0 was misstated, with the two-sided distributive law replacing the usual distributive laws.

Comment: @bof, thanks for the info, but I'm not seeing it. How does $0^2=0$ suffice? This is fun, by the way.

Comment: If $0^2=0$ then: $x0=(x+0)(0+0)=x0+x0\Rightarrow x0=0$, so $(x+y)z=(x+y)(z+0)=xz+yz$. Now, expanding $(0+0)(0+0)$ shows that the additive order of $0^2$ is either $1$ or $3$. To get a counterexample, take an Abelian group $(A,+)$ with an element $a$ of order $3$ and define $xy=a$ for all $x,y\in A$.